# Apply the epsilon delta definition of limit to the multivariable function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

The rigorous definition of limit for the function of two variable is given as following:

Give a function of two variables $f : D → \mathbb{R}, D ⊆ \mathbb{R}^2$
such that $D$ contains points arbitrarily close to a point $(a, b)$, we say that the
limit of $f (x, y)$ as $(x, y)$ approaches $(a, b)$ exists and has value $L$, if
and only if for every real number $ε > 0$ there exists a real number
$δ > 0$ such that

$$|f (x, y) − L| < ε$$

whenever
$$ 0 <\sqrt{(x − a)^2 + (y − b)^2}< δ.$$
we then write
$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)} f(x,y)=L.$$

I want to apply this definition to the function $ f(x,y)=e^{-x^2y},$ but unlike the single variable cases, I could not find a way to substitute the $δ$ in to the inequality, and then choose a minimum value to show that the $ε$  is bounded. Could some one help me on this problem? Thanks.

Comment: At what point $(a,b)$? $(0,0)$?

Comment: @angryavian, this is the general case, I need to show the function is continuous on it domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Warning: Using only first principles, this is extremely tedious.**

Let $(x_0,y_0)$ be given and fixed. First choose $\epsilon>0$ sufficiently small ($\epsilon<e^{-x_0^2y_0}$) so that
\begin{align}
0<e^{-x_0^2y_0}-\epsilon<e^{-x^2y}<e^{-x_0^2y_0}+\epsilon \\
\implies \ln(e^{-x_0^2y_0}-\epsilon)<-x^2y<\ln(e^{-x_0^2y_0}+\epsilon) \\
\implies \color{red}{\ln(e^{-x_0^2y_0}-\epsilon)+x_0^2 y_0}<\color{blue}{-x^2y+x_0^2 y_0}<\color{green}{\ln(e^{-x_0^2y_0}+\epsilon)+x_0^2 y_0}.
\end{align}
Note that the red is negative and the green is positive. By adding and subtracting $x^2y_0$ respectively, the middle term can be written as
\begin{align}
(x_0^2-x^2)y_0+x^2(y_0-y)=(x_0-x)(x_0+x)y_0+x^2(y_0-y). \label{*}\tag{*}
\end{align}
First start with $\delta_1=1$. Then $-1<x-x_0<1\implies -1+2x_0<x+x_0<1+2x_0$ so
$|x+x_0|\leq C_1(x_0):=\max\{|-1+2x_0|,|1+2x_0|\}$.

Similarly, $-1<x-x_0<1\implies x_0-1<x<x_0+1\implies |x|<C_2(x_0):=\max\{|x_0-1|,|x_0+1|\}.$ Therefore, \eqref{*} is bounded above by
$$
|x_0-x||x_0+x||y_0|+|x|^2|y_0-y|\leq C_1|y_0|\delta_2+C_2^2\delta_2=(C_1|y_0|+C_2^2)\delta_2
$$
with $\delta_2$ to be chosen. Choose $\delta_2=\frac{\ln(e^{-x_0^2y_0}+\epsilon)+x_0^2 y_0}{C_1|y_0|+C_2^2}$. This part takes care of showing the blue is less than the green above.

Similar techniques show \eqref{*} is bounded below by
$$
-|x_0-x||x_0+x||y_0|-|x|^2|y-y_0|\geq -(C_1|y_0|+C_2^2)\delta_3.
$$
Choose $\delta_3=-\frac{\ln(e^{-x_0^2y_0}-\epsilon)+x_0^2 y_0}{C_1|y_0|+C_2^2}$. This will take care of showing that the blue is greater than the red.

In conclusion, let $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2,\delta_3\}$. Then when $\sqrt{(x-x_0^2)+(y-y_0)^2}<\delta$, we will have red is less than blue is less than green. Working backwards shows $|e^{-x^2y}-e^{-x_0^2 y_0}|<\epsilon$.

If $\epsilon$ is not small, find $\epsilon_1<\epsilon$ that is and show everything is less than $\epsilon_1$ (using above). Then everything will be less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: If above is too hard to follow, consider proving that $e^x$ is continuous in one variable. The two variable case is similar, but more involved, using the fact that $\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}<\delta \implies |x-x_0|<\delta,\, |y-y_0|<\delta$.

Comment: Thank you very much, considering |x−x0|<δ,|y−y0|<δ would be easier for me. It is clear for me now.